# Xpath and css_selectors fail to extract dynamic content. (Using Python and Selenium)

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

**EDIT**: Thanks to the E Wiest for resolving my issue. You used some code that I'm not familiar with so you've given me some good learning material.

**Original post**: I'm using Selenium in Python to grab data on education statistics. I've been trying the entire day to extract one number -- the chronic absenteeism rate -- from the following website which contains information for the US state of Illinois: https://www.illinoisreportcard.com/School.aspx?schoolid=340491250130001 The number (in this case '10%') is located inside a div element with class "explanation."

```
<p class="image" id="thumb6" data-type="partition">
  <svg class="canvas" width="256" height="220" viewBox="0 0 256 220">...</svg>==0
  <div class="explanation" style="position: absolute; width: 110px; text-align: center; top: 82px; left: 73px;">10%</div>
</p>
```

I have tried all of the following and more, including with explicit waits, to select the div element containing this figure, but all have failed, typically resulting in NoSuchElementException:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('explanation')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='explanation']")
#Trying to reach parent element: 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@id='thumb6']")
driver.find_element_by_xpath(/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a[7]/p[1]/svg[1]/g[1]/rect[1])
```

I believe, but am not certain, that the problem may have something to do with dynamic content, but I'm not certain whether the HTML code is in fact dynamic since I've not previously encountered any. Can anyone help to understand why I cannot extract the figure?

Thanks. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need Selenium for this. First, build a list of urls. The pattern is :

```
https://rcc.isbe.net/api/reportcardservice/(en)/Domain(school)/Id(340491250130001)/(Profile)/(2019)/Table/(Xml)
```

Where `Id(340491250130001)` is the id of each school.`(2019)` is the year of interest. You can specify a range of years `(2016-2019)` if you want.

For each urls of your list, you need to obtain the ressource url containing the data. XPath :

```
//resourceUrl
```

You'll get something like :

```
https://sec.isbe.net/iircapi/tempData/XML/File1992993354.xml
```

For each xml file, you'll get the chronic absenteeism rate with :

```
//ChronicAbsenteeism
```

For example :

```
from lxml import html
import requests

data = requests.get('https://rcc.isbe.net/api/reportcardservice/(en)/Domain(school)/Id(340491250130001)/(Profile)/(2019)/Table/(Xml)')
root = html.fromstring(data.content)
xml=root.xpath('//resourceurl/text()')[0]

source = requests.get(xml)
tree = html.fromstring(source.content)
print(tree.xpath('//chronicabsenteeism/text()')[0])
```

Output : `10`

Comment: Hi E.Wiest, this was really helpful, thank you. Could you tell me what exactly the below code is, and how you knew to find that?  https://rcc.isbe.net/api/reportcardservice/(en)/Domain(school)/Id(340491250130001)/(Profile)/(2019)/Table/(Xml)

Comment: You can download the data in .xlsx format at the top of the page. This is a part of the download url.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the quick fix to that:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='explanation']").text() # This will fetch the innerHTML i.e. value of the div
```